# REVIT API StandardError: Unable to transform the body! : ILLEGAL_ENTITY_MODIFICATION -- entity modification outside API_BEGIN/END block

Tags: python, revit

I have build a script to place multiple panels on different Surfaces in Revit in different directions.
To make this possible I've made a simple python loop. There are still some problems to solve but the script works on small Surfaces.

When I make the Surfaces bigger I'm getting the following error:

> StandardError: Unable to transform the body! : ILLEGAL_ENTITY_MODIFICATION – entity modification outside API_BEGIN/END block
>   Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

I copied the script below:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variables.
#1 tot 100 tussenstap 10.
#geometry.translate(geometry,vector,afstand).

dataEnteringNode = IN

aantalsublsts = IN[0]
VectUassublsts = IN[1]
VectVassublsts = IN[2]
Geosublsts = IN[3]
vectorlengteVlst = IN[4]
afstandV = IN[5]
vectorlengteUlst = IN[6]
afstandU = IN[7]

n = 0

output = []

for x in range(aantalsublsts):
    Geo = Geosublsts[n]
    VectUas = VectUassublsts[n]
    VectVas = VectVassublsts[n]
    vectorlengteV = vectorlengteVlst[n]
    vectorlengteU = vectorlengteUlst[n]
    afstandenU = range(0,int(vectorlengteU),afstandU)
    afstandenV = range(0,int(vectorlengteV),afstandV)
    n = n + 1
    for y in afstandenU:
        for z in afstandenV:
            Geo2 = Geometry.Translate(Geo,VectUas,y)
            output.append(Geometry.Translate(Geo2,VectVas,z))

#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = output
```

Wouter Hilhorst

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if your code may not be running within a valid Revit API context.

How are you running this code?

Comment: It runs from within dynamo. The problem is already solved. The array got too big to calculate. I`ve combined several panels first and then made second array with less steps. I didn`t get the error after that.

Comment: I have the same problem only for 4 lines.
I dont change anything and its gone.
So maybe sometimes it depend of memory of computer.